# iOS 7 UINavigationBar - UIView layout issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-interface, ios7, uinavigationbar

Have a problem with layouts.

Here is how it looks right on iOS6:

[image]

Here is how looks on iOS7:

[image]

But it's ok.
And like described in [Apple's iOS7 TransitionGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/TransitionGuide.pdf)
I wrote one more stroke in `- (void)viewDidLoad`

```
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

And it now it's look like this:

[image]

Any suggestions? What can be wrong with my layouts?
 I want solid blue UINavigationBar. And have no idea, why the top of this is transparent.
Have any ideas, why it looks so strange? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

It is `YES` by default.

From the `UINavigationBar` documentation:

> New behavior on iOS 7.  Default is YES.  You may force an opaque
>   background by setting the property to NO.  If the navigation bar has a
>   custom background image, the default is inferred   from the alpha
>   values of the image—YES if it has any pixel with alpha < 1.0  If you
>   send setTranslucent:YES to a bar with an opaque custom background
>   image  it will apply a system opacity less than 1.0 to the image.  If
>   you send setTranslucent:NO to a bar with a translucent custom
>   background image  it will provide an opaque background for the image
>   using the bar's barTintColor if defined, or black  for UIBarStyleBlack
>   or white for UIBarStyleDefault if barTintColor is nil.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It's partly solve problem, but now colors looks a quite different. I hope, that exist way to leave navigationBar translucent, but fix layouts of tableView. What do you think about?

Comment: Might include that this can't be done in `-viewDidLoad:`. I couldn't figure out for the life of me why it wouldn't work and that was why. Be sure to put it in `-viewWillAppear:` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Add this line to your 'view will appear' method (if it is not there, add it by typing:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animate];

}
```

)

Then, at the bottom of viewWillAppear, underneath the [self viewWillAppear:] line, add this code:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeBottom];
```

This will make the top bar (nav bar) go opaque. In iOS 7, Obj-C now responds differently to whether or not the nav bar has been set to opaque, and this is a good way to gaurentee it works in both iOS 6 and 7 (there are some problems doing just:

```
navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

)

Hope this helps, I had the same problem when I converted an app to iOS 7 and it took ages to find a solution!

Comment: I believe you mean `[super viewWillAppear:animate]`. Otherwise that's an infinite loop.

Comment: This also fixed an issue I had where my app's behavior was different between the device and the simulator -- only the device needed a 64pt offset for the status/nav bar. Adding the setEdges... code worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4):

In IOS7 UINavigationBar style is Translucent by default so it will hide view Content Underneath, to show your content Under UInavigation bar write down following snippet in given method.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeBottom];
}
```