# How to get the blurred and translucent effect on a navigation bar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationbar

## Problem

My app appears to be laid out correctly, but I cannot achieve the blurry translucent effect that iOS 7 is famous for. Mine appears opaque.

[image]

## Desired Effect

I'm trying to get a more obvious blur effect such as Apple's Trailers app:

[image]

## Translucency

In my subclass of UINavigationController, I make the navigation bar translucent:

```
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    if (self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController]) {
        self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

## Tint Color

In my subclass of UIApplicationDelegate, I set the tint color of the navigation bar. I discovered that the alpha of the tint color makes no difference. That is, using an alpha of 0.1 would not cause the bar to become more translucent.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

## Edges

In my content view controller, I set the edge to `UIRectEdgeNone` so the top doesn't get [chopped off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081697/ios-7-navigation-bar-hiding-content) by the navigation bar. If I were to use the default `UIRectEdgeAll`, the navigation bar would permanently cover the top of my content. Even if I were to live with this abnormality, `UIRectEdgeAll` still does not enable the translucency effect.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

## Edit: Experimenting with Edges

Ad pointed out by @rmaddy in the comments, the problem may be with the edgesForExtendedLayout. I found a [comprehensive tutorial edgesForExtendedLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585104/1390119) and attempted to implement it:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
}
```

It did not work. Firstly, there was no translucency effect. Secondly, the top of my content was chopped off. On the following example page with the above code, the avatar was initially covered by the navigation bar and it was very hard to scroll to. You could pull down to see the top of the avatar, but when you let go, the page would automatically bounce back up and the avatar would be obscured again.

[image]

Comment: What device are you testing on? Not all devices show the blur effect.

Comment: And don't use `UIRectEdgeNone`. That defeats the effect. The effect only appears if the view controller goes under the navbar.

Comment: @rmaddy , The screenshot came on iPhone 5 with iOS 7.0.3 with the system "reduce animation" setting turned off. Using the default `UIRectEdgeAll` makes the top and bottom portion of the content view stuck under the navigation and tab bars, as I learned from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7). I've tried the default `UIRectEdgeAll` and it makes no difference in the special effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was caused by the third party pull-down-to-refresh view [EGORefreshTableHeaderView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/blob/master/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/Classes/View/EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m), which was popularly used before iOS 6 introduced the system refresh control.

[image]

This view confuses iOS 7, making it think that the content is taller than it really is. For iOS 6 and 7, I've conditionally switched to using [UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIRefreshControl/beginRefreshing). Now the navigation bar will not chop off my content. I can use `UIRectEdgeAll` to make my content go underneath the navigation bar. Finally, I tint my navigation bar with a lower alpha to get the translucency effect.

```
// mostly redundant calls, because they're all default
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5]];
```

Comment: Were you able to change the Alpha Value?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to achieve exactly the same effect as in the iTunes Store (Dark Blur).

Configure the `barStyle` attribute of the navigation bar as follows:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```