# NavigationBar clipping background image in iOS7 ;ClipsToBound:NO not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-image, navigationbar, clipped

I have set a background image slightly bigger than the navigationBar.The image is 55px in height.[I want a banner looking image with ribbon at the bottom of nav bar]
It was working ok in iOS6.
But in iOS7, its getting  clipped by itself.
I tried setting 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setClipsToBounds:NO];

It's still getting clipped.
Can't I have a bigger background image without getting clipped?

Comment: in iOS 7 navigation bar height is 64pts, use image with 64pts height to fit the view

Comment: I have rendered the status bar hidden and have set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO. Hence ,my navigation bar height is 44 px in iOS 7 as well.

Comment: in iOS 7 status bar resides over the naviagtionbar, even if you hide the status bar, height of the navigation bar remains same i.e. 64pts. Please refer ios7  transition guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1

Comment: I wonder why the self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height is printing 44.0 in the log.

Comment: I had to set ShadowImage property explicitly for iOS7 as mentioned in the docs.Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

this is due to  Ui navigation bar is 64 point in ios7 that why this create problem.
refer this **link** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html refer **table 5-1** that is give you idea that for resizable image what are the change in new ios7

you can use  UIBarPositioning propety to solve your problem not sure but that may help you 
refer this link for more info related to UIBarPositioning

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarPositioning_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UIBarPositioning/barPosition

Edited 
also try by set this flag
navigationBar.translucent = NO;

for more info refer this link 
[iOS 7 UINavigationBar - UIView layout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789225/ios-7-uinavigationbar-uiview-layout-issue)

Answer (score 0):

The image is not getting clipped, it is most probably just too small.
The UINavigationBar is 64 points in iOS 7, so the 55px image will be too small, especially considering the retina resolution where 128px would be needed.

Comment: I have rendered the status bar hidden and have set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO.
Hence ,my navigation bar height is 44 px in iOS 7 as well.

Comment: @swatiKaushik Still you will need to provide 88px image. Giving a 44px will cause elongation in retina devices.

Comment: Obviously.I do have both 44px And 88px images in my bundle.

Answer (score 0):

set the delegate of your navigation bar to your view controller, and return `UIBarPositionTopAttached` in delegate method. return the position which you want to see

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarPositioning_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIBarPositioning

Comment: HERE,https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarPositioning_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIBarPositioning      ,I read ,"Avoid using an extra-tall background image to display a custom drop shadow below the navigation bar. This technique won’t work in iOS 7"?!!
That's what I am doing it seems.